# g.Graphics.drawstring() Right to left align in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am try to print receipt with perfectly alignment. In here I need to print values .00  perfectly align. This is what I needed to out put
[Receipt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRqmv.png)

But I can't align all .00 values correctly.

this is the code I have tried

```
float maxwidth = Sendwidth(printCase, e, printFont7);

public static float Sendwidth(List<Case> printCase, PrintPageEventArgs e, Font font)
{
    float maxwidth = 0;
    foreach (var singlecase in printCase)
    {
        foreach (var Iteam in singlecase.IItemList)
        {
            string iteamAmount = ConvertNumericToStringAcordingToCulture(Iteam.IAmount);
            string iteamVat = ConvertNumericToStringAcordingToCulture(Iteam.IVatRate);
            string iteam = iteamAmount + "(" + iteamVat + "%)";
            SizeF amountstringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(iteam, font);
            if (maxwidth < amountstringSize.Width)
            {
                maxwidth = amountstringSize.Width;
            }
        }
    }
    return maxwidth;
}

PrintAlingmant(e, iiamount, printFont7, maxwidth, x, y);

public static void PrintAlingmant(PrintPageEventArgs e, string printamount, Font font, float maxwidth, float x, float y)
{
    SizeF amountstringSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(printamount, font);
    var format = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center };
    var rect = new RectangleF(x + 175, y, maxwidth, amountstringSize.Height);;
    e.Graphics.DrawString(printamount,font, Brushes.Black, rect, format);
}
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt at solving this?

Comment: I added code into post